# Data storage for the following program

Tags: database, dictionary, key

I have a problem where I need to display the best solution based on a fuzzy logic evaluation. It says that "if solution x has low resource wastage and low power consumption, then x is a good solution"

I am getting all the values for resource wastage and power consumption for all those x solutions. I want to store these resource wastage and power consumption into a data storage where x could be say a key for that storage and compare all the values for x solutions... whichever solution has low resource wastage AND low power consumption would display 'x' or key x as the best solution.

I tried looking at dictionary and hashtable, but they use the form ("key", "value"); but I want may be ("key", "value_resource", "value_power"). Which data storage can I use for this or how can I implement this??

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are a little unclear, but a key value store would allow you to store the key, and a value object where that object has both value_resource and value_power so a query against the objects in the store could be done to return results based on the value.

You could do this with an sql solution, or a no-sql solution.